# What problems do you encounter with VFP apps in a 64 bit environment?

Tags: 64-bit, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I know that there are issues with the VFP OLEDB provider on 64 bit machines. ... but what issues do you encounter while actually running a VFP application - on a 64 bit machine? Has anyone had any experience in this area?

My first thought was that it would just run as a 32bit app, without making use of the 64 bit power. However, I ran into difficulties with a FoxPro application connecting to a SQL Server database (probably an OLEDB issue as well). Are there other issues as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat of a specialized scenario, and it may not be related to 64 bitness, but since you asked...

My organization recently hosted a legacy VFP 7 app on a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise 64 bit server for access over Terminal Services.  The app runs fine, but there is some kind of bug with the TS Easy Print technology.  When you print from the app to a redirected client printer over Easy Print, the top, left, and bottom sides of each page of the document get clipped.  The workaround we use is to have the users print to pdfFactory on the server first, then print from pdfFactory to the redirected client printer over Easy Print.  Works great.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a stab in the dark...but I believe there are some drivers with MDAC that aren't available in x64 windows. I think you may be able to install the normal 32-bit  MDAC but it will install to the x86 folder.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen zero problems with our VFP9 apps on 64-bit XP, Server 2003, Vista, or Server 2008.

Our print engine is a VB DLL though, so we wouldn't run into any VFP-specific printing issues.